# Kivy Product Search Program

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import json
import re

class Grid(GridLayout):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Grid, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    # Columns for the main view
    self.cols = 1


    # Start of the Inside
    self.inside = GridLayout()
    self.inside.rows = 3


    self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = 'Enter the Brand Name for its Products: '))
    self.brand_input = TextInput(multiline = False)
    self.inside.add_widget(self.brand_input)


    # Add the things in inside to the main
    self.add_widget(self.inside)


    self.submit = Button(text = 'Submit', font_size = 20)
    self.submit.bind(on_press = self.pressed)
    self.add_widget(self.submit)


def pressed(self, instance):
    # Pull the text inside the textInput
    brand_name = self.brand_input.text

    with open('mcg_app/brands.json', 'r') as f:
        brands_dict = json.load(f)

    request = brands_dict[brand_name]
    modified_result = re.sub(r',\s(?![^(]*\))', "\n", str(request))

    self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = modified_result))

    # Clear out the fields after submitting
    self.brand_input.text = ''





class Mcg(App):

def build(self):
    return Grid()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    Mcg().run()
```

Hello, this program here has a text input box and the user inputs a brand name for example "Dove" after that he presses the submit button, and the button is connected to the pressed() function. Everything about the program is actually working fine the only problem is after I print the products of the entered brand let's say he inputs a different brand in that case the old output is still there so the program outputs new products with the old ones already there. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a sample json? App don't run without one..

Comment: Just keep a reference to the `Label` that contains the results. Then you can just replace its `text` rather than creating a new `Label` each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really test it without a `json` data file, but check out this:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import json
import re


class Grid(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Grid, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Columns for the main view
        self.cols = 1

        # Start of the Inside
        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.rows = 3

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text='Enter the Brand Name for its Products: '))
        self.brand_input = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.brand_input)

        # Add the things in inside to the main
        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.submit = Button(text='Submit', font_size=20)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.pressed)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)

    def pressed(self, instance):
        # Clear out the fields after submitting
        self.brand_input.text = ''
        self.inside.clear_widgets()
        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text='Enter the Brand Name for its Products: '))
        self.inside.add_widget(self.brand_input)

        # Pull the text inside the textInput
        brand_name = self.brand_input.text

        with open('mcg_app/brands.json', 'r') as f:
            brands_dict = json.load(f)

        request = brands_dict[brand_name]
        modified_result = re.sub(r',\s(?![^(]*\))', "\n", str(request))

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text=modified_result))


class Mcg(App):

    def build(self):
        return Grid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Mcg().run()
```

It resets the `self.inside` `GridLayout` on every button press...

Comment: Thank you so much man your code solved the issue. The only thing I needed to do was place the brand_name variable before clearing the widgets and now it works perfectly